# How do I combine observable of tuple elements with observable of single element?

Tags: ios, swift, observable, rx-swift

I have two streams of Observable, one with tuple of element `Observable<(E1, E2)>` and one with single element `Observable<E3>`. How do I combine these two streams of observable into `Observable<(E1, E2, E3)>`?

Comment: Combine so you get `Observable<((E1, E2), E3)>` then `map` to turn `((E1, E2) E3)` into `(E1, E2, E3)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can combine the Observer as like below. Hope it's help you

```
let combinedObservable = Observable.combineLatest(Observable<(E1, E2)>, Observable<E3>) {
       ($0.0, $0.1, $1)
   }
```